# htaccess redirect subdomain to folder and non-www to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, canonicalization

sub.domain.com redirect to www.domain.com/sub redirects using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.domain.com/sub/$1" [R=301,L]
```

domain.com/sub to www.domain.com/sub is where I'm stuck.The solutions I've found always drop the /sub/ folder when rewriting the www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/sub/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It was apparently too late. Had htaccess in the sub folder instead of root. Yours duplicates folder eg: domain /sub/sub/ Just needed to change the last line: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware that you wanna have your `.htaccess` inside `sub`. Usually, it's kept at the root. Please, change `RewriteBase` to `/sub` then (would only matter if you add a relative URL later on).